# Who created Allah Subhan Tallah?

Tags: islamic-philosophy

If Allah has created everything then who created Allah Sub Hana Tallah. What Quran explain in this regard?

This post is not a criteria to make judgment of our emaan upon Allah Subhana Tallah' saying. Its just a logical explanation for those who often raise above mentioned question. As I have not deny the fact that Allah is not created, even the starting point is that لَمۡ يَلِدۡ ۙ وَلَمۡ يُوۡلَدۡۙ.

Comment: Sura `Al-Ikhlas` (112) is for you to answer. Allah does not beget and was not begotten.

Comment: How you see things in this regard?

Comment: We don't see things. Our job is to believe. We believe in whatever Allah says. He is the Creator. He cannot be created, thus, was not created.

Comment: You ask, similar to  "If all things have a creator, then who created God?" Actually, only created things have a creator, so it's improper to lump God with his creation. God has revealed himself to us in the Bible & Quran as having always existed. God is the absolute being; totally different from the concept of gods in Paganism & Hinduism.

Comment: Yes, You are absolutely right that only created things have a creator, so it's improper to lump God with his creation. I have also mentioned the same thing in the post that Allah Subhan Tallah has invented the art of creation. He is الْمُصَوِّر, which is just an attribute of Him Just like other ones such as: ٱلْخَـٰلِقُ, ٱلْبَارِئُ, ٱلْعَزِيزُ, ٱلْحَكِيمُ , اَلْعَلِيْمُ. I have used the words just for common man like me who dnt have in-depth knowledge and such questions raise in their mind, even the first question of ashiest is the same

Comment: Muslim, You are right that our job is to believe. We believe in whatever Allah says. But it is necessary to make unbelievers realize things logically.

Comment: You will never make disbelievers realize things logically. Even Prophets could not do that, let alone a layman like you. Prophet Huh (AS) could not make his own son a believer. Prophet Lut (AS) could not make his own wife a believer. So, stop this useless debate and concentrate on doing more rightous deeds, if you are a believer yourself.

Comment: You mean to say that the duty Quran and our prophet has given us to invite people towards Allah Subhan Tallah should be left. No man its a duty of even a layman muslim

Comment: Surely, Hadayat is given only to those whom Allah want and even Prophets could not do that. But all the prophets had always tried to do that duty irrespective of the result

Comment: I want to add a hadith here. which shows that asking question for understanding religion is not prohibited.                                                       Safiyyah bint Shaybah reported: Aisha, may Allah be pleased with her, said, “How excellent are the women of the Ansar! They do not allow shyness to prevent them from understanding the religion.”

In another narration, Aisha said, “They do not allow shyness to prevent them from asking questions about the religion and seeking to understand it.”

Source: Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 332

Comment: This is a good question for good knowledge, even if it is just for someone to know how to answer this Q when asked by other people.  A good comprehensive answer will help a lot of people

Answer (score 2):

**If Allah created everything, then who created Allah**

**لَمۡ يَلِدۡ ۙ وَلَمۡ يُوۡلَدۡۙ**

**He did not beget, nor was He begotten.**

(Surah Ikhlas: 03)

This ayah is the answer to the concept of ignorance that Hazrat Isha a.s is Allah’s son and angels are His daughters.

“Has then your Lord (O pagans of Makkah!) preferred for you sons, and taken for Himself from among the angel daughters? Verily you indeed utter an awful saying.”

(Surah Israh:40)

**"…. The Messiah, Jesus, son of Mary, was only a Messenger of Allah…… Far be it from His glory that He should have a son…"**

(Surah Nisa:171).

However, if we assume that someone else has created Allah Subhan Tallah then that someone else is the real God. Again, we think that who created the real God? And the one who created the real God is the actual God. This chain of thought will continue in the same way without any conclusion. Its mean, Allah Subhan Tallah is not created by anyone but he himself has created everything.

If so, then why this thought comes into our mind that who has created Allah Subhan Tallah.

It is because Allah Subhan Tallah has created all the universe and then created us with limited thought. So, we think that everything has a creator behind it. Whereas Allah Subhan Tallah has invented the art of creation. He is **الْمُصَوِّر**, which is just an attribute of Allah Subhan Tallah Just like other ones such as:

**ٱلْخَـٰلِقُ, ٱلْبَارِئُ, ٱلْعَزِيزُ, ٱلْحَكِيمُ , اَلْعَلِيْمُ**

We human beings don’t create anything.  As we know that all the matter is the composition of atoms, proton, electron, neutron, etc. we just put together the created things or rearrange them. They are already created by Allah Subhan Tallah.

Newton law is already working in this universe. He has just rediscovered it. The lap top is created by putting together things, which are already recreated by others and others have again rearrange those things of someone else rediscoveries. However, the chain of recreation, rearrangement and rediscoveries is finally linked with the real and flawless creator, Allah Subhan Tallah.

A writer has rightly said:

**“**True science discovers God

Waiting behind every door.**”**

(Dan Brown).

“He is Allah: the Creator, the Inventor, the Shaper. He ˹alone˺ has the Most Beautiful Names. Whatever is in the heavens and the earth ˹constantly˺ glorifies Him. And He is the Almighty, All-Wise.”

(Surah Hashar: 24).

**اَللّٰهُمَّ اِنِّیْ اَعُوْذُبِكَ اَنْ اُشْرِكَ بِكَ وَ اَنَا اَعْلَمُ وَ اَسْتَغْفِرُكَ لِمَا لَا اَعْلَمُ**

**“Oh Allah, I take refuge in your lest I should commit shirk with you knowingly, and I seek your forgiveness for what I do unknowingly”**

(Altabrani: 4/10, Hisn al-Muslim: 203).

Answer (score 0):

Quran 3:2

> God, there is no god but He, the Living, the Eternal.

is the short and comprehensive answer to your question.

There is no deity prior to, apart from or besides God.

God is eternal. There is no time "before God" nor "after God".
God Was before the beginning of time and He will Be after the end of time.

Not even this, not speaking about anything beyond is observable through science but it is only known  through revelation.

The assumption - which cannot be part of Islamic philosophy because it rejects abovementioned revelation - that God was created and the question drawn thereof bites in its tail because any assumed per-creator would have to be created, too. This proves that this assumption is illogical, thus false.

Answer (score 0):

Until recently it was believed that the universe had always existed hence questions on its origin were ignored by the science community as " something that has always existed is in no need of a creator ". When clear evidence was found on the birth of the universe it was readily suppressed and ignored by the majority of the science community as, if released, it would pose the inevitable question of "if the universe had a start it means it was created by someone, who?" Science can't answer this question as science is only based on things we are able to observe and measure. The existence of a God is not only necessary but also evident by the very existence of humans. Nothing that has a start can deny the existence of its creator, since time and matter was created by Allah, He is beyond and independent to His creation. Since Allah isn't dependent on time or space He is The Only One that can exist without the need of a creator.